# Can't write to Firestore from Firebase Functions (same code was working a couple of days ago)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I had a working code that stopped working. It is a Firebase function that was writing some documents in Firestore. This is the code + the logs in Google Cloud Functions (I am using Flow for strong typing, and I blurred some of the confidential stuff):

[image]
[image]

[image]

Status page of Firebase and Google Cloud says that everything is fine. I checked my billing config and it seems ok. I made sure my libraries were not updated to any new version. My current versions below:

"firebase-admin": "8.2.0",

"firebase-functions": "3.0.2",

"firebase-tools": "7.0.0"

I did something that worked for a couple of hours: I downgraded the library firebase-tools@^7.0.0 to firebase-tools@7.0.0 (removed the ^), deleted the web app from my firebase project, and created a new one, and the function started working again. But only for a couple of hours.

I can't figure out what is happening. I would appreciate any help. Even if you don't have a solution, it would be helpful to know if you are experimenting something similar because this could be a new firebase bug too. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with stopped working? Any errors? Does the function complete?

Comment: Yes, the function completes successfully, but no data loaded. We don't see any errors in the log. But in the end, there is no data in the firestore database.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is related but your code does not do proper error handling.

First, your try/catch block inside the `storeDocInFirestore` function is not necessary because you return just a promise. The catch part is never reached.

Second, the catch method on the promise you return from the `storeDocInFirestore` function does not throw an error if something goes wrong. You just return the error message but the error itself is suppressed.

Third, it seems you use another try/catch block inside the cloud functionbut because you suppress the error from the Firestore operation your function always succeeds even if there is an error.

Maybe this causes your behavior.

**Edit:**

I think the problem is the `await promise.all(firestorePromises)` part.

If you do not have a `.catch()` method on `promise.all()` all promise errors are ignored.

Use `.catch(err => console.log(err))` method on `promise.all()` and you probably see a Firestore error.

Comment: If an error in the storeDocInFirestore happens, we want to suppress it. That is the desired behavior. We do log it, so if an error happens, we should know about it by looking at the logs. But as you can see in the oegs, it doesn't seem to be any errors.

Comment: I think i spotted something else. I have edited my answer. Hope this helps.